# Input data into BasicEditField on BlackBerry Torch

Tags: blackberry, keyboard, blackberry-torch

I'm writing an app which has a function asking users to type a filename into a BasicEditField on a PopupScreen.  The app works fine with Blackberry Storm 2 -- both the simulator and a real device.

The problem is that the app doesn't work on a BlackBerry Torch -- neither the simulator nor a device.  I can't enter text into the BasicEditField.

Why doesn't the keyboard on the BlackBerry Torch work with a BasicEditField? I've also tried an EditField instead of BasicEditField but it doesn't work either.

```
private BasicEditField txtFileName = 
    new BasicEditField("Name: ", "", 50, EditField.EDITABLE | EditField.FILTER_FILENAME);
...
Constructor()  
{  
    add(txtFileName);  
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, the mistake I made was to put the wrong return value for the **keyChar** method.
I put
**return true;**
at the end of the method,
which should be
 **return super.keyChar(key,status,time);**
Below is the correct implementation for the **keyChar** method:

```
public boolean keyChar(char key, int status, int time)
{
    ..................
    /*
    return true; // user cannot type in the BasicField on Torch, but can type on Storm
    */
    return super.keyChar(key,status,time);// works on both Torch and Storm
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This isn't an answer to your problem, but I have a code snippet that might help.  I tried reproducing what you describe above using the following code.  It worked without issue:

```
private static class AppScreen extends PopupScreen
{
     AppScreen() {
         super(new VerticalFieldManager(), Field.FOCUSABLE);

         BasicEditField txtFileName = new BasicEditField("Name: ", "", 50, 
                 EditField.EDITABLE | EditField.FILTER_FILENAME);
         add(txtFileName);
    }
}
```

Sorry I don't have a direct answer to your problem, but hopefully the above code can help you track down the problem in your app.

Comment: Thank you Fostah for quick reply! I'd track my code again and report back to you. Cheers !!!